# How to pass value to my CustomView programmatically?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

**attrs.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="InteractiveImageView">
        <attr name="play_anim" format="reference|integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**usage_example(`activity_main`).xml**

```
<com.doitandroid.mylottie.InteractiveImageView
    app:play_anim="@raw/icon_home">

</com.doitandroid.mylottie.InteractiveImageView>
```

When I want to add this view programmatically, How to do this?

**MainActivity.java**:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_ll);
InteractiveImageView interactiveImageView = new InteractiveImageView(this);
linearLayout.addView(interactiveImageView);
```

I don't know how to add `app:play_anim="@raw/icon_home"` this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a function on your custom view like

```
public void setPlayAnim(@RawRes int playAnim) {
        // do something 
}
```

then you can call from code like

```
interactiveImageView.setPlayAnim(R.raw.somthing)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have a constructor in the form of:

```
    public InteractiveImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    loadAttributes(attrs); //Here use the attributes.
}
```

Use AttributeSet to pass your values.

Example:

```
    private void loadAttributes(AttributeSet attrs) {
    if (attrs != null) {
        TypedArray typedArray = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.AudioPlayerView);
        mBackgroundDrawable = typedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.AudioPlayerView_player_background);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the `setLayoutParams` is required.

Comment: Ofc @Froyo just an example (Removed it)